# Rabi oscillations and two level dynamics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, oscillators

I'm currently looking at [Rabi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_problem) Oscillations, and not I have a look at the following equations:

$$W = \sqrt{\Omega^2+\delta^2}.$$

The amplitude:

$$\frac{|\Omega|^{2}}{\delta^{2}+|\Omega|^{2}}$$

Now, I see that if the detuning $\delta = (\omega - \omega_{0})$ is large, the two level approximation is bad, since the ratio between level 2 and 3 is getting closer to 1.
But why does the two level system not work for high $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1):

In the classical Rabi oscillation, where you solve the Bloch equations to find the dynamics of your spin-1/2 moment, you ALWAYS use a two-level system. The system is best suited for that, independent of your detuning.

Why? Because the a spin 1/2 system, which has two levels, is representable in the Bloch-sphere, which shows up as the equivalence between the SU(2) group and the SO(3) groups.

The case, in which the classical Bloch equations won't be sufficient, is the case when you have spins more than 1/2 (so more than 2 levels), and your Hamiltonian would make higher levels interactions to each other (which is rare). So if you have spin-1 system, for example, then the Bloch sphere would not be enough to represent the dynamics of your system, because the Bloch-sphere looks only at the *orientation* of your system, which is a vector quantity that you classically represent by the Bloch vector. If you have a higher spin, then a contribution would show up from higher multipole moments, which is *alignment* rather than orientation, that are represented with higher order tensors $T^{(K)}$.

Luckily, even though higher multipole moments could exist in many atoms, their effect isn't really pronounced. The reason is that we usually use light to interact with atoms, and light as polarizations which could be either linear $(\pi)$ or circularly polarized $(\sigma^+,\sigma^-)$, or a superposition of those. Therefore the interaction of higher orders would only exist in a pronounced way if you push your system to have not only dipole transitions, but also quardrupole and octupole and higher order transitions.

The most complicated case with light is when you have linearly polarized light for pumping. In that case you'll induce alignment rather than orientation. A paper that discusses that is this:

http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0605234

For more details, look at the irreducible representations of Multipole moments. It's a huge topic, into which I wouldn't recommend going, unless you have something to do with research. The article would give you an introduction into that.

Good luck, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When $|\delta| \gg |\Omega|$ you are far from population inversion. In addition the time-scale of the small and fast population oscillations (or wiggles) is driven by the system (interaction-free) Hamiltonian. In the opposite limit, $|\delta| \ll |\Omega|$, you have population inversion and the frequency of the oscillations is given by the strength of the coupling, $\Omega$.

There might be or not problems with the Rabi formula for large $\Omega$ depending on how do you define large, I mean, on how large is $\Omega$ compared with. There is no general problem with $|\Omega| \gg |\delta|$. This is as simple to meet as to chose a resonant driving field.

However, $|\Omega|$ can be large with respect to other physical parameters that break the limit of validity of the 2-level Hamiltonian. Then the Rabi solution is no longer an accurate solution for the true Hamiltonian (or the true dynamics) of the system.

Within the two-level description of the system the Rabi solution breaks down when the duration of the external field $\tau$ is shorter than $|\Omega|^{-1}$ or when $|\Omega|$ is larger than the energy difference between the levels $|E_2 - E_1|$.

More typically, for large $|\Omega|$ other quantum states, not included in the 2-level Hamiltonian, may be excited, for which, obviously, the Rabi solution gives no adequate description of the dynamics.